# Getting exception on calling a DisplayALert() in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to launch a alert box in xamarin forms with the following code, but the call fails with the below exception.

```
private async void ProfileEmailAddressViewModel_UpdatedPersonalDetailsEvent(object source, UpdateEmployeePersonalDetailsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Result)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Exception Details: `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
  at UIKit.UIApplication.EnsureUIThread () [0x0001a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:88 
  at UIKit.UIView.set_BackgroundColor (UIKit.UIColor value) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIView.g.cs:2817 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.PresentAlert (Xamarin.Forms.Internals.AlertArguments arguments) [0x0000d]`

Please let me know if anyone had faced a similar issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason, you're not calling this from the UI thread.

Wrap the call in the `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (async () => {
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
});
```

While you are doing something on a background thread and you want to interact with the UI, you will need the `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` method to invoke it on the main thread which is responsible for the UI.

Comment: Thank you Gerald. Worked perfectly.

Comment: It says Device is obsolete so use MainThread instead.

Answer (score 0):

Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread is deprecated, use this:

```
Dispatcher.Dispatch( async () => {
await DisplayAlert("Alert", "You have been alerted", "OK");
});
```